# Extend navbar with CSS using Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to extend this navbar and prevent it from collapsing when window shrinks

Here's what it currently looks like
[image: Current Effect]

Here's what I'm trying to make it look like
[image: Desired Effect]

This is my first Bootstrap project, here's my current code:

HTML:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <img src="images/tacticIDLogo.png" height="125" width="240" border="0" />
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is My CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:#000000;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.navbar-nav{
    margin-top:30px;
    background-color:#000000;
    float:right;
}
.container{
    width:960px;
    min-width:960px;
    max-width:960px;
}
.navbar {
  background-color:#000000;
  height:100px; 
  border:0px;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a {
  background-color:#000000;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color:#000000;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a {
  background-color:#000000;
}
```

I've been battling with it for an hour and I feel stupid because I can easily achieve this without bootstrap. Any help would be awesome... I also have Modernizr called on this, not sure if that has any effect on this.

Comment: Just give your navbar a width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to add a wrapper div to `ul.navbar-nav`

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <img src="images/tacticIDLogo.png" height="125" width="240" border="0" />
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      ....
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And add some CSS

```
.nav-wrapper {
  height: 50px;
  background-color:#333;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.navbar-nav {
  float: right
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4jGz3/1/